# Work done moving a particle in a force field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the work done moving a particle in the force field:

F = $x^2i + xyj + z^2k$

Along the straight line from $(0,0,0)$ to $(2,1,2)$

I've attempted the question by parameterising the line using the method:

$(1-t)(0,0,0) + t(2,1,2)$ = $(2t,t,2t)$

Is this where I am going wrong?

The part I struggle with in these types of questions is always the parameterisation.

Comment: Why don't you try seeing if the force field is conservative?

Comment: The question asks us to solve it, I know you can take the curl to see if it is conservative, which in this case it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing just fine. So you want to integrate from $t=0$ which corresponds to the origin to $t = 1$ which corresponds to the endpoint using the standard definition of work done i.e find $dr$, find the dot product betwen $F$ and $dr$, substitute the parametric form to each variable and integrate.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was integrating between t = 0 and t = 2.

Comment: So when parameterising in terms of x, it's always between t = 0 and t  = 1?

Comment: No it depends on the endpoint and and the origin of the path.

Comment: Could you elaborate? In this case how did it depend on the  origin and endpoint?

Comment: The question wants you to find work done from $(0,0,0)$ to $(2,1,2)$. You have the parametric equation $r(t) = t(2,1,2)$. You need to choose the value of $t$ which describes the particle path.

Comment: How would I parameterise the same F, over the helix $x=cost, y = sint, z= t$

Comment: Or wait, are those already the parameterisations?